# Php url space replace with dash(-) by .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've php link like that

```
echo "<h4><a href='$bname_d'>$bname_d</a></h4>'
```

If **$bname_d = Creativeartbd host company** then the url is show

```
http://mysite.com/Creativeartbd host company (2 space in this url)
```

So how do i replace this space with dash by php/.htaccess ?

Currently I used following .htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /businesspage.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the url through this 
      `<?php
      $bname_d = str_replace(' ','-',$bname_d);
      ?>`
that will replace spaces with '-'

Comment: If i used this url structure than i can't get the result from db. Because of, now i get the all details from this url from db and there is now dash in db.